# generating jpg thumbnails in dotnet

Tags: c#, image

i am using this code to take a jpg image and save it as a thumbnail but it seems very slow ..

```
        Image thumbNail = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, new IntPtr());
```

is there any faster way to generate a large amount of thumbnails from a directory of images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Draw Image - **Re Edited**

```
    public Image ResizeImage(Image openImage, int NewWidth, int NewHeight) {
        var openBitmap = new Bitmap(openImage);
        var newBitmap = new Bitmap(NewWidth, NewHeight);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(openBitmap))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.DrawImage(newBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, NewWidth, NewHeight));
        }
        openBitmap.Dispose(); //Clear The Old Large Bitmap From Memory

        return (Image)newBitmap;
    }
```

Typical 3-4mb Image Takes Between 4-8ms

Comment: what if i want it to be a jpg

Comment: as the original image is a jpg

Comment: this is inside a function that returns an "Image" is there anyway to have this code return an image object that is a jpg versus saving it ?

Comment: jpeg is a storage form, why do you need it as a jpg?

Comment: @mek above is a sample of a function that will resize an image. Saving can be done using save method on the bitmap

Comment: @mek -> newBitmap.Save(TargetStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg); will save the bitmap to the stream of your choosing as a Jpeg. Other formats are found in the ImageFormat enum

Comment: since the current implementation: image.GetThumbnailImage() returns an Image object, i want to maintain the same interface so i can create some IThumbnailGenerator abstraction ..  i need a way to return an image object.

Comment: @mek the bitmap class inherits from the image class

Answer (score 6):

1)  By far the fastest and most reliable way to create .Jpg thumbnails is to use partial decompression.

Jpg's have a unique aspect in that it's possible to extract a 1/8 size or 1/16 size (or any power of 2 size) copy of the original **without decompressing or sampling** the entire original image.

Ever notice how programs like Picassa or Windows Explorer seem to create thumbnails super fast?  This is how they do it (when they are not already cached).

This functionality is easily available in any library based on the Independent JPEG Group library code, and most of them are.  For example ImageMagick which has a .NET layer available.

2)  You can further increase speed by using a hardware accelerated library like [libjpeg turbo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/), although it may require interop.

3)  Some explanation of this special .jpg feature is [here](http://jpegclub.org/djpeg/).

Comment: Warning: Magick.NET (ImageMagick's .NET layer) is windows only.

Comment: Hi @Lee, can you explain you that works in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210285/create-thumbnail-for-winforms-picturebox-with?noredirect=1#comment85431966_49210285 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
public bool GenerateThumbNail(string fileName, string thumbNailFileName,
    ImageFormat format, int height, int width)
{
    try
    {
        using (Image img = Image.FromFile(fileName))
        {
            Image thumbNail = new Bitmap(width, height, img.PixelFormat);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(thumbNail);
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            g.DrawImage(img, rect);
            thumbNail.Save(thumbNailFileName, format);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It uses DrawImage too.