# C# generating thumbnails filesize

Tags: c#, thumbnails

I have the following code to take an image and generate the thumbnail.

how can I alter the quality or compression to get smaller file sizes programatically?

```
Image thumbNail = image.GetThumbnailImage(Width, Height, null, new IntPtr());
```

Comment: -1 for Asking the same question again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684092/create-thumbnail-and-reduce-image-size

Comment: Just how often do you have to ask the same question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672807/generating-jpg-thumbnails-in-dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly need better control over the thumbnails produced, you will be better off producing your own by manually generating an image of smaller size and different quality.  The GetThumbnailImage dows not give you much control.

See this article for how it's done.
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing

Answer (score 1):

When saving the `thumbNail` with [`Image.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80.aspx) you can specify the quality by passing a [`EncoderParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter.aspx). See: *[Reducing JPEG Picture Quality using C#](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial232_Reducing-JPEG-Picture-Quality-using-Csharp.html)*

```
EncoderParameter epQuality = new EncoderParameter(
    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality,
    (int)numQual.Value);

...
newImage.Save(..., iciJpegCodec, epParameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not use the GetThumbnailImage API:

```
protected Stream ResizeImage(string source, int width, int height) {
            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(source))
            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap newBmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height)) 
            using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newBmp))
            {

                graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphic.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphic.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                graphic.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, width, height);

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                newBmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                return ms;

            }             
        }
```